# Unit Testing Java Script - Fake XRM with QUnit

Tags: javascript, mocking, qunit

I have a `js` function which I want to unit test using `QUnit`. It is a simple function where I pass the field name that I want to hide from the form. I am also using a Mocking framework from here: [link] https://github.com/ambek/XrmPage-Mock

```
function HideField(field) {
    Xrm.Page.getControl(field).setVisible(false);
};
```

My Tests.js file looks like this:

```
var Xrm;

QUnit.test("Testing Hide Field Function", function (assert) {

    var PageControls = new Array();
    PageControls.push(CreateSimpleControlWithAttribute("NewField", "M",  "Type of Residence"));
    var page = new XrmPageMock("{607C16D1-7C53-4023-B20B-13E4F1C6A9D3}", PageControls, 1);
    Xrm = new XrmPageMock(page);
    HideField('NewField');
    assert.equal(XRM.page.getControl('NewField').getVisible(),false,  'Passsed');

});
```

On executing my tests, I get this error:

> Unable to get property 'getControl' of undefined or null reference

Does anyone know why my mocking/faking is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a typo in the following statement:

`assert.equal(XRM.page.getControl('NewField').getVisible(),false,  'Passsed');`

The new statement is (Correction on the word "page")

`assert.equal(XRM.Page.getControl('NewField').getVisible(),false,  'Passsed');`